F15 Startup Intake drop
So I’m aware that the F15 has intake Ramps that adjust to airspeed and AOA, in order to ensure that the airflow is entering the engine smoothly and not too fast. But why does the system drop the first intake ramp when the engine is starting up?
Why would it restrict airflow at idle power?

Picture link - http://form.univ-mosta.dz/?y=til-f-15-fighter-jets-air-intakes-are-variable-zz-2an4X3sL

Not sure I understand the question completely. Why not have it go ahead and drop to the take-off position at that time?  Or perhaps the question is why do the ramps lock in the up position at shut down?

Is it actually "necessary", or is that simply what you observe?  Perhaps it's just a byproduct of hydraulic pressure being available or not?

My guess it's to have the intake ramp aligned with the incoming flow during high-angle-of-attack situations like take-off and landing.

@ROIMaison This is what I have been thinking. I guess it’s just my odd mechanical obsession.

when the intake takes in supersonic air the engine may experience turbulence and hence get damaged. Hence, the inlets are responsible for turning the supersonic air into subsonic such that the engine is able to handle it. when the air goes supersonic the first ramp opens up, the second ramp converges to make sure the air reaching the engine goes subsonic and intern not damage. Similarly, when subsonic air enters, the first ramp converges as the second ramp opens up to allow for "increased" airflow. This helps prevent stalls during start up and/or overwhelm the engine.
Later on during flight both the ramps open up (during subsonic flow).
I hope this answers your question, much of this has been researched using Quora and Google:
https://www.quora.com/Why-are-F15-jet-air-intakes-pointing-a-bit-downwards-and-not-straight
I did find it hard to understand so I've simplified it in my own words.

You really just added detail to what the OP explained that they already knew in the first sentence.

yes, but I added more details to solve his question

Thanks for the extra info!! I’ve visited the page before but didn’t really find anything about the reason for them coming down during startup.

@Boeing787 Glad I could help!
